# Could not delete database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `aspnet-Ebuy-20151210093351`. I use the command:

```
drop database aspnet-Ebuy-20151210093351
```

to delete it, but I cannot do it, I get an error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the database name with brackets, without which SQL Server will interpret the dashes `-` as being subtraction symbols.

```
drop database [aspnet-Ebuy-20151210093351]
```

Comment: Good on ya for fixing your answer :) You also need to ensure the command is executed from the `master` database.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the table name in Brackets []?

```
drop database [aspnet-Ebuy-20151210093351]
```